# Ionic 2 - Expected Expression Error

Tags: web, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, development-environment

I am currently working on an app using the Ionic 2 framework. After adding an SCSS variable, I suddenly got this weird error which tells me that there is a missing "(". I removed everything and the error still persisted. Even in a completely new project, the error continues to exist. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You provide an extra image (other than the error screenshot), but you don't explain what it is.  Also, you mention "SCSS", but your error message indicates "CSS".

Comment: What's on line 36 of `variables.scss`?